# Check if a String contains multiple values in Java without using OR operators?

Tags: java, refactoring, operators, contains

I have a code here that's checking if a record's title contains one of the four values that we want to ignore. If the title contains the 4 strings, we would like to put it in the database and set the `state` to `IGNORE`. If it doesn't, we still want to put it in the database and set the `state` to `NEW` for later processing.

The code works, however, it is a bit of an eye sore. How could I write this in a cleaner, more efficient, easier to read way?

```
 if (
    record.getTitle().contains("word") ||
    record.getTitle().contains("different word") ||
    record.getTitle().contains("phrase") ||
    record.getTitle().contains("different phrase")
  ) {
    int id = dao.insert(nv);
    nvRecord =
      NV
        .builder()
        .from(nv)
        .setId(id)
        .setState(state.IGNORE)
        .build();
  } else {
    int id = dao.insert(nv);
    nvRecord =
      NV
        .builder()
        .from(nv)
        .setId(id)
        .setState(state.NEW)
        .build();
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a *regular expression* for "Title" followed by one, two, three or four. Like,

```
if (record.getTitle().matches("Title [1234]")) {
```

Or compile a `Pattern` and use a `Matcher` like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Title [1234]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(title);
if (m.matches()) {
```

Based on your updated requirements, stream a `List` of your special titles and check if the record title contains it. Like,

```
if (List.of("Titanic", "The Great Gatsby", "Catch Me If You Can", "Inception")
        .stream().anyMatch(record.getTitle()::contains))
```

Comment: You don't need `|` inside a character class. Should be `[1234]` or `[1-4]`.

Comment: @khelwood Good point. I wasn't thinking about that part (clearly).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I forgot to specify that the titles are vastly different from one another and do not follow a pattern. For example: "Titanic", "The Great Gatsby", "Catch Me If You Can", "Inception"

Comment: `if (List.of("Titanic", "The Great Gatsby", "Catch Me If You Can", "Inception").stream().anyMatch(record.getTitle()::contains))`

Comment: Thank you so much! That is a lot cleaner!